# Error 500 when trying to upload to AWS S3 with multer-s3

Tags: javascript, express, amazon-s3, multer

I am using express + multer-S3 to upload files to AWS S3. Using the following code, I get an internal server error 500 and I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

```
const aws = require("aws-sdk");
console.log("Require AWS");
const multer = require("multer");
const multerS3 = require("multer-s3");

const s3 = new aws.S3();

aws.config.update({
  secretAccessKey: process.env.S3_ACCESS_SECRET,
  accessKeyId: process.env.S3_ACCESS_KEY,
  region: "eu-west-3",
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (file.mimetype === "image/jpeg" || file.mimetype === "image/png") {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(new Error("Invalid file type, only JPEG and PNG is allowed!"), false);
  }
};

const upload = multer({
  fileFilter,
  storage: multerS3({
    acl: "public-read",
    s3: s3,
    bucket: "schubox",
    contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE,
    metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
      console.log("Called when saving image  to AWS");
      cb(null, { fieldName: "TESTING_METADATA" });
    },
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      console.log("FILE ==> " + JSON.stringify(file));
      cb(null, Date.now().toString());
    },
  }),
});
```

And in my route

```
router
  .route("/rayons")
  .get(auth, ctrlRayons.rayonsListe)
  .post(auth, **upload.single("fichier")**, ctrlRayons.rayonsCreerUn);
```

I get this error

> Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1"
>
> Error: connect EHOSTDOWN 169.254.169.254:80 - Local (192.168.1.10:56879) at internalConnect (net.js:934:16) at defaultTriggerAsyncIdScope (internal/async_hooks.js:452:18) at net.js:1022:9 at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)

What am I doing wrong?
My AWS S3 account is ok, I have my Id and my secret ok, but nothing is written in my bucket. All the tutorials show the same procedure as the one I use.

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: What is the **full** error?

Comment: the only thing I see is "Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG" and "<pre>Error: connect EHOSTDOWN 169.254.169.254:80 - Local (192.168.1.10:56879)
    at internalConnect (net.js:934:16)
    at defaultTriggerAsyncIdScope (internal/async_hooks.js:452:18)
    at net.js:1022:9
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)</pre>

Comment: Pleae update the Q with that - are you running this locally?

Comment: Yes, I am running locally for the moment.

Comment: `process.env.S3_ACCESS_SECRET` & `process.env.S3_ACCESS_KEY` definitely hvae values? Have you tried console logging them?

Comment: Yes, I confirm, I tried logging then and they are correctly valued. Is there something to do with the AWS CLI that I am not using?

Comment: Yes I am using dotenv

Comment: Move `aws.config.update`... above `const s3` - does that work?